# How to select a row in GuiGridView based on row cell value?

Tags: c#, automation, frameworks, sap-gui

I want to select a row based on a particular cell value from SAP **GuiGridView**, able to find a method to select columns **grd.SelectColumn("")**.

The similar manner I want to select a particular row.

I am able to retrieve the row data by looping through the grid. But not able to select the row.

Currently, I am filtering the grid using SAP filter functionality and doing the rest of my process.

Comment: I got it    grd.SetCurrentCell(3, "");
            grd.SelectedRows = "3";

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ALV grid only loads first 64 rows, how to change default load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54709653/alv-grid-only-loads-first-64-rows-how-to-change-default-load)

Comment: I guess what you're talking about is the property `SelectedRows` of [GuiGridView](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/sap_gui_for_windows/760.02/en-US?q=GuiGridView): `grd.SelectedRows = "1,2,4-8,10"`