# Can't read all rows from GuiGridView. Getting blank after 34 rows

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, sap-gui

I am doing SAP automation, there I am reading data from `GuiGridview` and adding to a `DataTable` using a for loop. But after 34 rows every values are empty. Then I tried with setting the current cell using a condition

if (rowindex % 34== 0)
grd.SetCurrentCell(rowindex, grd.FirstVisibleColumn);

After that I am able to get the values of 35, 36th row but again then blank values from there. The total I am having is 91 rows.

Comment: Please tell us whether you could make your code work with the current answer?

Answer (score 1):

The backend doesn't send all the grid rows to the frontend, only the ones currently viewed.

You must scroll the grid via the property `FirstVisibleRow`, and use the other properties `RowCount` and `VisibleRowCount` to scroll only when required.

Example:

```
for (int rowindex = 0; rowindex < grd.RowCount; rowindex = rowindex + 1)
{
  // Position at top if first time or scroll to display next page
  if ( rowindex % grd.VisibleRowCount == 0 )
  {
    grd.FirstVisibleRow = rowindex
  }
  // Process the line
  ...
}
```

More information: [SAP Library - GuiGridView](https://help.sap.com/docs/sap_gui_for_windows?locale=en-US&q=GuiGridView)