# SAP GridView Get value

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I'm trying to get data from SAP Gridview to the excel file,

It worked as for now, however, I've encounter an issue when if the row count is a lot, it will not get everything from the data, for example, my row count is 240, it will only get 52 like that.
is there any limitation loop/range from GridView?

So far below is my code:

```
session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/NZFPAYADVINFO"
session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSP$00001-LOW").Text = "AR02"
session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").setCurrentCell -1, "AVIK-AVTXT"
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").selectColumn "AVIK-AVTXT"
session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[29]").press
session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_FREESEL:SAPLSSEL:1105/btn%_%%DYN001_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press
session.FindById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[24]").press
session.FindById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
session.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").currentCellColumn = "AVIK-AVSID"


Dim myGrid2 As Object

Set myGrid2 = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell")

allRows = myGrid2.RowCount - 1 ' Number of SAP rows

allCols = myGrid2.ColumnCount - 1 ' Number of SAP Columns

Dim columns2 As Object

Set columns2 = myGrid2.ColumnOrder ' SAP column names in order in SAP window

For i = 0 To allRows

   Cells(i + 4, 1).Value = myGrid2.GetCellValue(i, columns2(1))
   
Next i

MsgBox ("Completed")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't read all rows from GUIGridView. Getting blank after 34 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65576298/cant-read-all-rows-from-guigridview-getting-blank-after-34-rows)

Comment: Maybe this helps https://blogs.sap.com/2012/04/02/tip-write-each-table-with-sap-gui-scripting-to-a-csv-file/

Answer (score 1):

The backend doesn't send all the grid rows to the frontend, only the ones currently viewed.

You must scroll the grid via the property `FirstVisibleRow`, and use the other properties `RowCount` and `VisibleRowCount` to scroll only when required.

Example:

```vb
For rowindex = 0 to grd.RowCount - 1
  ' Position at top if first time or scroll to display next page
  If rowindex mod grd.VisibleRowCount = 0 Then
    grd.FirstVisibleRow = rowindex
  End If

  ' Process the line
  ...
Next
```

More information: [SAP Library - GuiGridView](https://help.sap.com/docs/sap_gui_for_windows?locale=en-US&q=GuiGridView)

NB: this answer is the copy of [my answer for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65576298/cant-read-all-rows-from-guigridview-getting-blank-after-34-rows) and adapted to VBA.